# SparkSQL regexp_extract function java error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to extract the id's starting with `srsa` from the table structure below

```
id      reason_text_field 
34394   {"initial_customer":"sda_WWyfr4AXY1fIAS", customer_result":"srsa_CAkAaAvNKL2OSD"}
```

in order to get the following output:

```
id      srsa_id 
34394   srsa_CAkAaAvNKL2OSD
```

but when I use the following SparkSQL function

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(reason_text_field, 'srsa[^"]*') as srsa_id
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the group to capture. Try this:

```sql
SELECT  id, 
        REGEXP_EXTRACT(reason_text_field, '\"(srsa[^"]*)\"', 1) as srsa_id
        -- or REGEXP_EXTRACT(reason_text_field, 'srsa[^"]*', 0) as srsa_id
FROM    tb
```

Note however that you can also convert the text column `reason_text_field` into a map or struct using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#from_json) then extract the field `customer_result`:

```sql
SELECT  id, 
        from_json(reason_text_field, 'map<string,string>')['customer_result'] as srsa_id
FROM    tb
```